# Are mass and charge of a black hole related to each other?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, mass, charge

While scrolling through an online document, I came across the statement, "If charges carried by the black hole are large, the curvature at the horizon is small." How is this so?

I tried to think of an answer to this. My thinking goes this way: I know curvature is related to mass. If an object is more massive, it bends the spacetime fabric more, producing large curvature. So curvature small means mass small. So how does a large charge mean a small mass for a black hole? What is the relationship between the charge and mass of a black hole?

Comment: You may be interested in the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric#The_metric) for charged, non-rotating black holes (for simplicity). It explains that "the electric field energy also contributes to the total mass."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Physical interpretation of the Reissner-Nordstrom metric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222137/)

Comment: Usually when you use the various definitions of mass for charged BH, you will find that even the electric charge of BH will contribute to its final mass